# Pivot dataframe into one level / rename df.pivot() output columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot

I have a dataframe, `df_res` with volumetric and mean and standard deviation jacobian values against ID strings (`subjid`), software type ran (`pipeline`), and anatomical region labels (`label_id`):

```
df_res = 

       subjid   pipeline   label_id    volume_(mm^3)    mean_jacobian    stdev_jacobian
0   100007_t0      Rigid          0       10100000.0             1.11             0.078
1   100007_t0      Rigid          1         315439.0          1.04635             0.283
2   100007_t0      Rigid          2         624165.0         0.968231             0.192
3   100007_t0      Rigid          3         515589.0           1.1273             0.229
4   100007_t1      Rigid          0       10084600.0           1.0935             0.033
5   100007_t1      Rigid          1         320533.0           1.0457             0.277
6   100007_t1      Rigid          2         621393.0            0.957             0.193
7   100007_t1      Rigid          3         507840.0          1.00573             0.232
```

My goal dataframe is something where I would want to have one row per `subjid`-`pipeline` pair, and the `label_id` is almost transposed as column per quantity.

**The preview below is a "condensed version" for formatting's sake**.

Assume that each `label_id` from `df_res` has its own `{label_id}_volume_(mm^3)`, `{label_id}_mean_jacobian`, and `{label_id}_stdev_jacobian` columns (total of 9 for each `label_id`+ `pipeline` + `subjid` = 11 total columns):

```
df_goal = 

subjid      pipeline    label0_volume_(mm^3)   +...+  label3_volume_(mm^3)   +...+  label3_mean_jacobian
100007_t0      Rigid              10100000.0                      515589.0          1.1273
100007_t1      Rigid              10084600.0                      507840.0         1.00573
```

I managed to get something close, with `df_res_test`. I did a `df.pivot()` function:

```
>>> df_res_pivot = df_res.pivot(index="subjid", columns="label_id", values=["volume_(mm^3)", "mean_jacobian", "stdev_jacobian"])

df_res_pivot = 

          volume_(mm^3)                      ... stdev_jacobian                    
label_id              0         1         2  ...              1         2         3
subjid                                       ...                                   
100007_t0    10100000.0  315439.0  624165.0  ...       0.289318  0.192214  0.229341
100007_t1    10084600.0  320533.0  621393.0  ...       0.277735  0.193940  0.232486

[2 rows x 12 columns]
```

Is there a way I can rename / combine the `values` and `columns` argument to make my data more sensible and look like `df_goal`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df = df.pivot(index=["subjid", "pipeline"], columns=["label_id"])
df.columns = [f"label{b}_{a}" for a, b in df.columns]

print(df.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
      subjid pipeline  label0_volume_(mm^3)  label1_volume_(mm^3)  label2_volume_(mm^3)  label3_volume_(mm^3)  label0_mean_jacobian  label1_mean_jacobian  label2_mean_jacobian  label3_mean_jacobian  label0_stdev_jacobian  label1_stdev_jacobian  label2_stdev_jacobian  label3_stdev_jacobian
0  100007_t0    Rigid            10100000.0              315439.0              624165.0              515589.0                1.1100               1.04635              0.968231               1.12730                  0.078                  0.283                  0.192                  0.229
1  100007_t1    Rigid            10084600.0              320533.0              621393.0              507840.0                1.0935               1.04570              0.957000               1.00573                  0.033                  0.277                  0.193                  0.232
```

---

EDIT: With the dataframe `df_res_pivot` you have in your question:

```py
df_res_pivot = df.pivot(
    index="subjid",
    columns="label_id",
    values=["volume_(mm^3)", "mean_jacobian", "stdev_jacobian"],
)

df_res_pivot.columns = [f"label{b}_{a}" for a, b in df_res_pivot.columns]

print(df_res_pivot.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
      subjid  label0_volume_(mm^3)  label1_volume_(mm^3)  label2_volume_(mm^3)  label3_volume_(mm^3)  label0_mean_jacobian  label1_mean_jacobian  label2_mean_jacobian  label3_mean_jacobian  label0_stdev_jacobian  label1_stdev_jacobian  label2_stdev_jacobian  label3_stdev_jacobian
0  100007_t0            10100000.0              315439.0              624165.0              515589.0                1.1100               1.04635              0.968231               1.12730                  0.078                  0.283                  0.192                  0.229
1  100007_t1            10084600.0              320533.0              621393.0              507840.0                1.0935               1.04570              0.957000               1.00573                  0.033                  0.277                  0.193                  0.232
```

Comment: Would this be done on my resultant `df.pivot` output? (`df_res_pivot`)?

Comment: @florence-y It should be the same (just change `df_res_pivot.columns` after pivoting). See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

@AndrejKesely's solution is great. Another option is with [pivot_wider](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_wider) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), using the `names_glue` parameter:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(df
.pivot_wider(
     index = ['subjid', 'pipeline'], 
     names_from = 'label_id', 
     flatten_levels=True, 
     names_glue = "label{label_id}_{_value}")
)
      subjid pipeline  label0_volume_(mm^3)  label1_volume_(mm^3)  ...  label0_stdev_jacobian  label1_stdev_jacobian  label2_stdev_jacobian  label3_stdev_jacobian
0  100007_t0    Rigid            10100000.0              315439.0  ...                  0.078                  0.283                  0.192                  0.229
1  100007_t1    Rigid            10084600.0              320533.0  ...                  0.033                  0.277                  0.193                  0.232
```